# circumventing browser security for a demo

Tags: security, browser

I have a demo to make in which first a secure session is created with domain (let's call it paranoids.com), and then a bunch of locally read html+javascript (my demo) want to use that secure session. We are using google-chrome, started with --disable-web-security and --allow-file-access-from-files, on a linux/openSuse platform.

Why do I need to do that? I need to scrape some pages from that domain and re-render them with an alternative renderer. We have absolutely no say with that other domain owner.

What's the best possible approach for this, without asking my poor breadgiver to go through technical hoops? Can my script access the JSESSIONID of the domain paranoids.com when run with some command line arguments? Or, is it just not possible, and must the user  copy/paste the cookie manually?

Thanks for any ideas that help realize that goal.

Comment: Secure session = HTTPS and tokens passed as cookies?

Comment: Practically everyone uses something like JSESSIONID, but there could be a lot more going on underneath that I don't know about. After all, some state must be passed back n forth, somehow. In any event, I can see the cookie, can copy n paste it into my code and use it freely, but I would like to automate that step so that my demo remains focused.